# Switching lights in a matrix

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I'm interested in papers and articles on the following problems (not necessarily solutions).  At least is there a name to these that I can lookup ?

Say that $a_{ij} \in \{-1, +1\}$ for $1 \leq i, j \leq n$.  Think of the $a_{ij}$ as lights turned on $(+1)$ or off $(-1)$.

We are allowed to flip lights on rows and columns.  That is, for all $1 \leq k \leq n$, flipping row $i$ sets $a_{ik} \gets -a_{ik}$ , whereas flipping column $j$ sets $a_{kj} \gets -a_{kj}$.

What is the maximum lights that can be lit ?
Is there an algorithm that finds this maximum (and the rows/columns to flip) efficiently ?  It sounds NP-Hard, but is there something published on the topic ?

In "The Probabilistic Method" by Alon and Spencer, a lower bound for the first question is given - though it's non-constructive.
I'm especially interested in the algorithmic aspects of these questions.

Comment: The "at most once" restriction in the second question is unnecessary as doing it twice (even with intermediate steps) is the same as not doing it at all.

Comment: Points to note: there are $2^{n^2}$ patterns of lights but $2^{2n}$ patterns of switches; and every pattern of switches has a pair producing the same result (e.g. flipping all the columns is paired with flipping all the rows).

Comment: You're right !  That simplifies the question.  I guess my question now would be : is there an algorithm that determines the rows/columns to flip to maximize the lights on.  It sounds NP-hard, but I'd like to know if there's something published on it.

Answer (score 2):

Flipping rows/columns is like multiplying the matrix $A$ with an invertible matrix from the left or the right.

Since the target is a matrix of all ones, which has rank one, it follows that only initial configurations with rank one can be turned to all-on. For instance, starting with 
$$
\pmatrix{1 & -1 & -1 \\ -1&1&-1\\-1&-1&1}
$$
will never produce a matrix full of ones.

One can also prove that $A$ having rank one is sufficient: If $A$ has rank one,
all rows are multiples of the first row, either by a factor $1$ or $-1$. Now, one can flip each row if necessary such that it is equal to the first row. Then flip all columns containing $-1$s:
$$
\pmatrix{1&-1\\-1&1}
\to 
\pmatrix{1&-1\\1&-1} \to \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}
$$

Comment: Ah yes, Henry found that out in the comments (implicitly).  I edited my question to be more precise about what I'm looking for.  Sorry for the late edit.